# Python -- exposing numpy array core component in a wrapper class

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a class that wraps a numpy array like so:

```
class FooArray(object):
    def __init__(self, array):
        self._internal_array = array

    @property
    def internal_array(self):
        return self._internal_array

    def __array__(self):
        """So FooArray can be used with numpy operations"""
        return self.internal_array
```

I would like to, for example, call `foo.shape` where `foo` is an instance of `FooArray`. But when I do I get `AttributeError: 'FooArray' object has no attribute 'shape'`. Why doesn't this work as expected? I've checked [numpy docs on this matter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.classes.html) but it's still unclear to me.

Comment: The docs say that `__array__` is for when your object is used as the `out` parameter of a ufunc. `foo.shape` is not using your object as the `out` parameter of a ufunc.

Comment: How would you expect `foo.shape` to work? You don't actually call any numpy functions anywhere in your example, so nothing is even going to look at `__array__`.

Comment: You're correct; e.g., `np.max(foo)` works, accessing the internal array and returning the max value. But is there a way I can do attribute lookup as well?

Comment: `np.asarray(foo).theattribute` will do the job. Lots of attributes can be spelt as `np.attribute(x)` instead of `x.attribute`, such as `shape` and `ndim`

Comment: Thank you @Eric, that attr access works well. Ideally though the client would be able to access them as `foo.attribute` so the same client code that operates on np.ndarray would operate on `FooArray` without having to change.

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain: Are you sure you don't just want to subclass `ndarray`?